# Position fixed div inside another fixed div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a fixed div to the bottom inside another fixed div. I have seen on stackoverflow that we can use an absolute div as a wrapper to position a fixed div

Here levelTwo div is fixed and wrapper levelTemp is absolute to align the fixed child div to the bottom and levelThree is the fixed child div.
The expected output for me should be like this:
[image: EXPECTED]
but it is like this:
[image: ACTUAL]
**Solution 1:**
One way is to specify height of the levelTemp div of 50px but in my case the height of levelThree div can vary.

```
.levelOne {
    position: relative;
}

.levelTwo {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: gray;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}

.levelTemp {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.levelThree {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="levelOne">
    <div class="levelTwo">
        <div class="levelTemp">
            <div class="levelThree">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if both are supposed to be fixed, the only one need to be fixed and the other can simply be absolute.

Comment: yes you're right, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using `position:fixed`**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.levelOne {
  position: relative;
}

.levelTwo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: gray;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

.levelTemp {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.levelThree {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="levelOne">
  <div class="levelTwo">
    <div class="levelTemp">
      <div class="levelThree">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**using `position:absolute;`**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.levelOne {
  position: relative;
}

.levelTwo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.levelTemp {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.levelThree {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="levelOne">
  <div class="levelTwo">
    <div class="levelTemp">
      <div class="levelThree">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```
.levelTemp {
   /* bottom: 0; */
   /* overflow: hidden; */
   bottom: 0;
   position: absolute;
 }
 .levelThree {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background: red;
   /* position: fixed; */
   /* bottom: 0; */
  }
```